# NO Property value exists for the ID

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

> Error querying database.
> Cause: org.springframework.dao.DatalnegrityViolationException: No    property value exists for ID 16814326
>
> org.springframework.dao.DatalntegrityViolationException! Cause:No property yalue exists ior 1D 1081320
>
> at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapExcepton(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
> at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSglSession.selcect(DefaultSglSession.java:144)

Comment: Error message is pretty straightforward. You have problem with integrity of your database. Have you backup of Alfresco. Did you try restore it?

Comment: I have made a data backup. Do you mean to restore the database?

Comment: Yes, restore the database. But I would also prefer to restore the contentstore just to be safe.

Comment: The backup of the database was made a few days ago. Restoring the database backup with a backup will cause part of the data to be lost. Is there any other way?

Comment: On your place i will test if that old backup running without this error. Just to be sure that you have some running backup.

Comment: When I was performing a database integrity check task, I found that the execution did not end for several hours.

Comment: Exhaustive search of 'dbo.alf_prop_value, idx_alf_propv_per' (database ID 6) for inconsistencies completed.  Processed 1 of 1 total searches.  Elapsed time: 42267 milliseconds.  This is an informational message only. No user action is required.